# Http Streams with Java

Tags: java, json, streaming, feed

I'm looking for the best way to stream live data over the http protocol with java.

I'm currently using [HttpURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to receive json feeds, I would like to know if it can be used to stream feeds too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the "best" way to stream HTTP and JSON, I would suggest going with [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) and [Jackson JSON library](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

However, if you are just looking for streaming of a HttpURLConnection, the getInputStream method should provide for that.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), which is more evoluated.

Comment: Apache HTTP Client (3.x) is deprecated. Current code is in HttpComponents: http://hc.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

I like the [Jersey Client](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with).  But really, you could probably pick any of these large framework components and have a decent solution.  The difference maker is preference, e.g. I like the builder methods that the client provides, but you could use 100% Spring with the CXF [JaxWsProxyFactoryBean](http://docs.huihoo.com/apache/cxf/2.0/jax-ws-configuration.html).